# Permalink-based website in Zend Framework, how to route requests

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am building a small weblog / site app in ZF. I have been building it to be similar to Wordpress, and each "page" has it's own permalink stored in the DB.

I am having trouble getting Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite to behave properly.

What I am trying to do is something similar to this:

- Request starts http://site.com/zend-framework-melts-my-brain
- Content table is searched for a row with the permalink "zend-framework-melts-my-brain"
- "zend-framework-melts-my-brain" row is of type "page"
- Controller:Frontend Action: Page gets executed
- I am a happy programmer.

Is this something I would need to write a plugin for, or am I overcomplicating this problem?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

See this blog post I wrote a while ago: http://tfountain.co.uk/blog/2010/9/9/vanity-urls-zend-framework. The post is for vanity URLs but the solution is the same.